# Wordpress Custom Menu Usage

Tags: wordpress

I have a menu(CSS + HTML) like below. How can I use this menu in WordPress?

http://jsfiddle.net/MadCodeMonkey/hv6a4pzk/

I tried something but it didn't work. It looks like in the image:

[image]

If anyone can help, can send me the correct codes?

Functions.php

```
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'my-custom-menu' => __( 'My Custom Menu' ),
      'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
```

Single.php

```
      <?php 
   $defaults = array(
         'theme_location'  => 'my-custom-menu',
         'container'       => 'ul',
         'menu_class'      => '',
        
   );

  wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
  ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not necessarily an easy question to answer. In order to use your own custom HTML, you'll need to create your own Class to extend the `Walker_Nav_Menu` Class: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116708/customizing-walker-nav-menu - that should get you started. Or, paste your HTML into `single.php`, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will try :)